# How to make bokeh server work with __name__ == "__main__"

Tags: bokeh, serve

I want to use python code for Bokeh server and use it as library as well. So I modularize my code by `_name_=='__main__'`, but standalone Bokeh server is not getting triggered.

```
def initialize_WatchDataFrame():

     print("Initialize Watchlist")

if __name__ == "__main__":       

    initialize_WatchDataFrame()

    curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update_WatchDataFrame, 2000)
    curdoc().title = "WatchList"
```

So when i was running the server with "bokeh serve Watchlist.py". I dont see the call to initialize_WatchDataFrame() being made.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to run `python foo.py` and don't want to run `bokeh serve foo.py` then you you will have to [embed the Bokeh server as library](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#embedding-bokeh-server-as-a-library). That requires setting up and starting a Tornado `IOLoop` manually yourself. Here is a complete example:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

def modify_doc(doc):
    p = figure()
    p.line([1,2,3,4,5], [3,4,2,7,5], line_width=2)
    doc.add_root(p)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = Server({'/bkapp': modify_doc}, io_loop=IOLoop())
    server.start()
    server.io_loop.start()
```

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you may also need to embed this app using `server_document`, or run the `IOLoop` in a thread. Those use cases are demonstrated in the examples linked in the docs.

It probably also bears mentioning: the code that modifies the document *only runs when a browser connection is made*. (And: it is run *every* time a browser connection is made, to generate a new document just for that session.)

Comment: Thanks for the response !  How does one embed this code above, when i try to run this i get "RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running"

Comment: Even when i am running https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/1.1.0/examples/howto/server_embed/standalone_embed.py  example i am getting error RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

Comment: Make sure you have a recent version of Tornado.